# Why is Times New Roman the default font for high school papers instead of Times?

Tags: fonts, font-design

It seems to me that Times is a superior font. On Microsoft Word at least, Times supports ligatures and Times New Roman doesn't. It may just be personal preference, but the symbols for Times are far superior. Why does Times New Roman always get preference over Times?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

... because Times New Roman is a default installed font on Windows systems I believe.

Few people will ever even realize there's a difference and even fewer would care that there's a difference.

This is all similar to why people use Arial (yuck) over Helvetica. They just don't see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Because Microsoft did not care about fonts. At least in the past. And their (sometimes stolen) default choices did become the standard.